# Is there a device that confines the sound in the surroundings of the mouth or face

Tags: sound-devices

Is there any device in the market that allows a person to speak at any volume, but the sound remains confined/enclosed in the area of surroundings of the mouth or face. The idea is to work in places with high restriction of sound levels, and be able to record the sound, not necessarily wireless.

Comment: Well , sound travels through air , and a human needs air so i find it difficult, tho a simple device utilizing a broadband absorbtion material would cut a lot, but only the challenge of not letting air come out at all is a big one.. some offices use standard cubical desks with absorption materials which work well! Modern open space designs , full of glass and reflective surfaces just make the sound unbearable...

Comment: Ditto to the last comment and also when you say “register” do you mean “record?”

Comment: fixed the "register" issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a product called ISOVOX 2 that surrounds the head to be portable to record in any environment:

https://isovoxbooth.com/?v=79cba1185463

You might want to check that out. Be warned though, it's quite expensive!

Comment: It also makes you look a whole lot more stupid than a lip mic ;)

Comment: If you attach it to your head, just remember to duck for low door ways ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A fighter pilot oxygen mask?  Lots of those on Ebay.  Probably a bit obtrusive and might be some effort to get the air supply working well enough for recording.